# BlueImp fileupload not triggered in function

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I try to trigger the BlueImp file upload as follows:

```
function upload(fileinput){
console.log('in upload');

fileinput = $(fileinput);
console.log(fileinput);

fileinput.fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {

    },
    always: function(e, data){
        if(data.jqXHR.responseText == 'fixedImage'){
            showLoader('ad', 'table');
            updateAdTable('ad', 'table');
        }
        else{
            theBackend.prepend(data.jqXHR.responseText);
            $('#cropForm').modal('show');
            cropper();
        }
    },
    progressall: function(e, data){
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        console.log(progress);
    }
});

}

theBackend.on('change', '[id^="nav_table_ad_id_"]', function(){
    upload($(this));

});
```

As my title says, I am trying to trigger the plugin by calling a function so I can reuse this feature. But for some reason it doesn't fire the plugin. Can please someone help me or explain me what am I doing wrong?

Kind regards,

Pim

Answer (score 0):

Is the on change actually working? Do you need to initialize the fileupload plugin on change? Can you call the input observer on page load?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution :)
As I said the idea of triggering the plugin using a function would made it possible for me to reuse the plugin on several different occassions. As I was reading the docs, the plugin is initialized on an id-attribute from some element. I interpreted that in a way as when you trigger for example onclick, as in $('.selector').click(...)

It is in a way the same but I thought that it should/could only be trigger onchange. But calling the function on for example document ready did the trick. And on the places I needed/could need the feature again.

So the problem was not how but when/where I called the function and trigger the fileupload plugin